# Error Page Redirection for Php Db errors when user changes parameters in Url

Tags: php, mysql, url, redirect, parameters

I have a php page in which i use $_GET to get a variable from a previous page.

So in this page I have declared it

example

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$car=$_GET['car'];
```

And then I have some php functions which uses this variable.

So the url to this page looks somthing like

```
www.example.com/secondpage?id=1&car=1
```

Now if a user edits this url and deletes id=1, my second page shows a mysql error...... how to redirect this to an error page whenever someone plays around with a url and as a result there is a mysql error.....?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If any of the given answer helped you - please accept it to give reward to this person :)

Answer (score 0):

Your could do a redirect with Statuscode 302. Therefor you can user [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
if(empty($id) || empty($car)){
    header("location: http://www.example.com/my_error_page.html");
}
```

Important is that this statement is executed before any output is made. [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks if the parameter is 0, "" or null. So its not checking if the supplied id is actually existing.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in the very beginning of your script:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'] || empty($_GET['id'] || !isset($_GET['cart'] || empty($_GET['cart'])
    header('Location: error.php');
```

Note the restrictions on both the `empty` and the `header` function: `empty` will return true for `"0"`, for example, while `header` cannot be called if any output has been sent by. Refer to the manual for further restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

On your secondpage.php, when you do the function to get the information:

```
$variable = $_GET['variableA']
```

change it to this:

```
$variable = $_GET['variableA']
if(isset($variable))
{
    //Do something if ID exists
}
else
{
    //Do Error Handling or header redirect
}
```

This gets the variable, if its not there it will be null. The IF ststement checks if it is a value (not null) and execute your code, if it is null then the else statements run, here is where you put the error message.

You can use the header to redirect to another p[age BUT this has to be run before any code is sent to the page (includes html and php echo).

To add other statements in, just add them to the if statement.

```
if(isset($variable) && isset($variable2))
```